# User permissions for /dev/tty* in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, containers, device

I'm trying to create a docker image with development tools for Arduino, but it fails to communicate to the serial port.

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN echo "Acquire::http::Proxy \"http://172.17.0.2:3142\";" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10aptprox

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo \
    make \
    build-essential \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    cmake \
    picocom \
    gcc-avr \
    avr-libc \
    avrdude \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Configure the user
ARG uid
RUN useradd -M --uid $uid --user-group user --groups uucp,dialout \
    && echo 'user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/user \
    && echo 'Defaults exempt_group+=${user}' >> /etc/sudoers.d/user \
    && chmod a=r,o= /etc/sudoers.d/user
USER user
```

(The cache is there so it doesn't download the packages on every iteration of the Dockerfile ;-) ).

This is how I build it:

```
docker build -t ard_cont --build-arg uid=$(id -u) .
```

Launch it:

```
docker run --rm -it -u $(id -u):$(id -g) --device /dev/ttyUSB0 ardev bash
```

And, when I try to get something out:

```
user@866782740b3a:/$ echo "Hello world" >> /dev/ttyUSB0 
bash: /dev/ttyUSB0: Permission denied
user@866782740b3a:/$ sudo su
root@866782740b3a:/# echo "Hello world" >> /dev/ttyUSB0 
root@866782740b3a:/#
```

So, I don't know how to configure the user so it can access the device.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I've managed to share devices with Docker container during `docker run` phase, was tinkering directly with cgroup rules or rather Docker's `--device-cgroup-rule`.

For that to work we have to figure out major and minor numbers of the device in question. While looking at [Linux kernel documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt), we can figure aout that `/dev/ttyUSBx` stands for "Character device with major device number being 188 (dec)"

To doublecheck that we can issue the following:

```
$ stat -c '%F %Hr %Lr' /dev/ttyUSB0
character special file bc 0
```

(beware, that the numbers provided are in hex, for more up-to-date distro and `GNU Core utils` the following could be used:

```
$ stat -c '%F %t %T'
character special file 188 0
```

With this information in hand, we can start `Docker` container while sharing the device in question by issuing:

```
$ docker docker run --device-cgroup-rule='c 188:0 rmw' --rm --name our_fancy_container -t our_fancy_image:latest
```

Last step for this to work (done inside the container environment):

```
$ docker exec --user 0 our_fancy_container mknod -m 0666 /dev/ttyUSB c 0xbc 0x0
```

**Note**

In case of "permission denied" kind of errors, you may need to work with `udev` rules and fix permissions for `/dev/ttyUSB0` on the host side as well (0666).

`Docker` documentation on `--device-cgroup-rule`:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#device-cgroup-rule

And to make it plug-an-playable (or hot-pluggable), you'll need delve into the realm of `udev` rules.